# How to add a card to a user and charge it using Stripe?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, credit-card

I have a page where a user enters a cc and get's charged.

I create a card token using js

```
Stripe.card.createToken(ccData, function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) { 
    var token = response.id;

    // add the cc info to the user using
    // charge the cc for an amount
});
```

To add the cc I'm using php

```
$stripeResp = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($stripeUserId);
$stripeResp->sources->create(['source' => $cardToken]);
```

To charge the cc I'm using php as well

```
$stripeCharge = Stripe_Charge::create([
    'source'      => $token,
    'amount'      => $amount
]);
```

Doing all this i get `You cannot use a Stripe token more than once`.

Any ideas how can i save the cc to this user `$stripeUserId` and charge it.

PHP is welcome, but js is great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

> **Saving credit card details for later**
>
> Stripe tokens can only be used once, but that doesn't mean you have to
>   request your customer's card details for every payment. Stripe
>   provides a Customer object type that makes it easy to save this—and
>   other—information for later use.
>
> Instead of charging the card immediately, create a new Customer,
>   saving the token on the Customer in the process. This will let you
>   charge the customer at any point in the future:

(example follows in multiple languages). PHP version:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("yourkey");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create a Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Example customer")
);

// Charge the Customer instead of the card
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer->id)
);

// YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later!

// YOUR CODE: When it's time to charge the customer again, retrieve the customer ID!

\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount"   => 1500, // $15.00 this time
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customerId // Previously stored, then retrieved
  ));
```

> After creating a customer in Stripe with a stored payment method, you
>   can charge that customer at any point in time by passing the customer
>   ID—instead of a card representation—in the charge request. Be certain
>   to store the customer ID on your side for later use.

More info at https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-customer

Stripe have excellent documentation, please read it!